# TypeError: 'int' object is not callable in Python (3.7)

Tags: python, for-loop

I am trying to write the following formula in Python (3.7):

[CBA formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oSazi.png)

But unfortunately I am getting a TypeError: 'int' object is not callable . Below is the code I am trying to run:

```
import numpy as np

##CBA
cm=np.array([[20,0,0],[1,14,0],[0,0,13]])
print(cm)

for i in range(3):
    a = cm[i,i]
    sum1 = cm[i,0]+cm[i,1]+cm[i,2]
    sum2 = cm[0,i] + cm[1,i] + cm[2,i]
    eq = ((a / max(sum1,sum2))/3)
    add = sum(eq)
    print(add)
```

Here is the code output and error message:

```
[[20  0  0]
 [ 1 14  0]
 [ 0  0 13]]

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-1-72bf927660e0>", line 17, in <module>
    add = sum(eq)

TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object is not iterable
```

How can I sum the `eq` variable?

Comment: This occurs because you have unwisely used `sum` as a variable name.  Choose a better name, and you won't hide the Python `sum` function.  In THAT sequence, you are not actually using `sum`, so you can just delete the `sum = 0` line.

Comment: In `add = sum(eq)`, you are actually writing `add = 0(eq)` and 0 isn't callable.

Comment: @TimRoberts I deleted `sum=0` and got another error: TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object is not iterable.

Comment: @matth You should make a [mcve] that can be copied and run *with no changes* to produce the error claimed.  `numpy` is not imported and `confusion_matrix`/`y_test`/`y_pred` are undefined.  A full stack trace indicating the path and line of error is also needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `eq` is just a single variable (and not an array), then you don't use the `sum` function at all.  You would need:

```
##CBA
cm=confusion_matrix(y_test,y_pred)

sumx = 0
for i in range(3):
    a = cm[i,i]
    sum1 = cm[i,0] + cm[i,1] + cm[i,2]
    sum2 = cm[0,i] + cm[1,i] + cm[2,i]
    sumx += ((a / max(sum1,sum2))/3)
print(sumx)
print(sumx/3)
```

However, there are many potential improvements to this.  If `cm` is a numpy array, then you can sum up a column or a row at a time:

```
for i in range(3):
    a = cm[i,i]
    sum1 = np.sum(cm[i,:])
    sum2 = np.sum(cm[:,i])
    sumx += ((a / max(sum1,sum2))/3)
```